# @return type for function returns $this

Tags: php, comments, phpdoc

if I have a PHP function like this :

```
private function sampleFunction()
{
    //Do something

    return $this;
}
```

What should be the `@return` type in the doc block comment ?

Can I use like `@return $this` ?

Basically I am using this for method chaining.

Comment: the return type is the name of the class of which $this is an instance.